# Как упростить Retrofit Singleton?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, singleton

Здравствуйте.

Имеется несколько моделей: JSON Pojo + Retrofit и Singleton. Подошёл к осознанию того что мой Singleton не правильный (либо его можно значительно упростить) и нужен профессиональный взгляд на код.

Singleton:

```
public class RetrofitSingleton {

private static final String TAG = RetrofitSingleton.class.getSimpleName();

private static Observable<Response<Buildings>> observableRetrofitBuilding;
private static BehaviorSubject<Response<Buildings>> observableBuilding;

private static Observable<Response<Apartment>> observableRetrofitApartmentByID;
private static BehaviorSubject<Response<Apartment>> observableApartmentByID;

private static Subscription subscription;
private static APIService apiService;

private RetrofitSingleton() {

}

public static void init() {
    Log.d(TAG, "[ Singleton ] | init()");
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().create()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build();
    apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
}

public static void resetBuildingObservable() {
    Log.d(TAG, "[ Singleton ] | resetBuildingObservable()");
    observableBuilding = BehaviorSubject.create();

    if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    subscription = observableRetrofitBuilding.subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<Buildings>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            observableBuilding.onError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response<Buildings> categoriesCall) {
            observableBuilding.onNext(categoriesCall);
        }
    });
}

public static void resetApartmentByIDObservable() {
    Log.d(TAG, "[ Singleton ] | resetApartmentByIDObservable()");
    observableApartmentByID = BehaviorSubject.create();

    if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    subscription = observableRetrofitApartmentByID.subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<Apartment>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            observableApartmentByID.onError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response<Apartment> productsCall) {
            observableApartmentByID.onNext(productsCall);
        }
    });
}


public static Observable<Response<Apartment>> getApartmentByIDObservable(Integer id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "[ Singleton ] | getApartmentByIDObservable(" + id + ")");
    observableRetrofitApartmentByID = apiService.getApartmentByID(id);
    if (observableApartmentByID == null) {
        resetApartmentByIDObservable();
    }
    return observableApartmentByID;
}


public static Observable<Response<Buildings>> getBuildingObservable() {
    Log.d(TAG, "[ Singleton ] | getBuildingObservable()");
    observableRetrofitBuilding = apiService.getBuildings();
    if (observableBuilding == null) {
        resetBuildingObservable();
    }
    return observableBuilding;
}
}
```

APIService

```
public interface APIService {

@POST("get_buildings/")
Observable<Response<Buildings>> getBuildings();

@POST("get_buildings/get_apartment_by_id/{id}")
Observable<Response<Apartment>> getApartmentByID(@Path("id") Integer id); 
}
```

JSON Моделей может быть огромное множество и в связи с этим вопрос: Мне придётся в Singleton под каждую модель создавать обработку? Или это можно как то решить примерно так:

```
public class RetrofitSingleton {

private static final String TAG = RetrofitSingleton.class.getSimpleName();

private static Observable<Response<Object>> observableRetrofit;
private static BehaviorSubject<Response<Object>> observable;

private static Subscription subscription;
private static APIService apiService;

private RetrofitSingleton() {

}

public static void init() {
    Log.d(TAG, "[ Singleton ] | init()");
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().create()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build();
    apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
}

public static void resetObservable() {
    Log.d(TAG, "[ Singleton ] | resetObservable()");
    observable = BehaviorSubject.create();

    if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    subscription = observableRetrofit.subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            observable.onError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response<Object> categoriesCall) {
            observable.onNext(categoriesCall);
        }
    });
}

public static Observable<Response<Object>> getObservable() {
    Log.d(TAG, "[ Singleton ] | getObservable()");
    observableRetrofit = apiService.getBuildings();
    if (observable == null) {
        resetObservable();
    }
    return observable;
}
}
```

Заменив каждую модель на Object но тогда как построить правильный APIService и вызов самого Singleton?

Comment: А для чего у вас вообще методы reset*Observable()? Да и вообще весь этот синглтон?

Comment: Множество фрагментов, повороты экрана, контроль над тем загружаются ли данные в момент поворота экрана или нет, дабы не плодить в каждом фрагменте инициализацию нового Retrofit объекта да и с Singleton хотелось поработать.

Answer (score 1):

Я не претендую на самый правильный вариант. Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {

public static final HttpService httpService = new HttpService();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}}
```

HttpService:

```
public class HttpService {

protected HttpApiFactory httpApiFactory;
private CompositeSubscription subscription = new CompositeSubscription();

public HttpService(HttpApiFactory httpApiFactory) {
    this.httpApiFactory = httpApiFactory;
}

public void subscribeAction(@NonNull HttpApiFactory.HttpMethodType type, @NonNull Action1 action, Func1 error, Object query) {
    Observable observable = httpApiFactory.getHttpMethod(type, query);

    if (observable != null) {
        subscription.add(observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .onErrorResumeNext(error)
                .subscribe(action, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e("httpService", "Ошибка в action");
                    }
                }));
    }
}

public void unsubscribe() {
    subscription.clear();
}
```

}

HttpApiFactory:

```
public class HttpApiFactory {

protected HttpApi httpApi;

public HttpApiFactory(Retrofit retrofit) {
    httpApi = retrofit.create(HttpApi.class);
}

public enum HttpMethodType {
    GET_CATEGORY,GET_PAID_SERVICE, GET_REGIONS
}

public Observable getHttpMethod(HttpMethodType type, Object query) {
    Observable observable = null;
    switch (type) {
        case GET_CATEGORY:
            observable = httpApi.getCategory((String) query);
            break;
        case GET_PAID_SERVICE:
            observable = httpApi.getPaidServices();
            break;
        case GET_REGIONS:
            observable = httpApi.getRegions();
            break;

    return observable;
}
```

}